# Tikz horizontally align group of matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Can someone help me aligning horizontally the first two matrices so that they will be centered with respect to the others below?
[image]

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum width=8mm, draw},
    },
    ]
    \matrix[mymatrix] (A1) 
    {
        2&8&7&1&3&5&6&|[fill=green]|4\\
    };
 %%%%   
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A1] (A2) 
    {
        2&1&3&|[fill=lightgray]|4&7&5&6&8\\
    };
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A2] (A31) 
    {
        |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
    };
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A31] (A3) 
    {
        2&1&|[fill=green]|3&\\
    };
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A31] (A32) 
    {
        7&5&6&|[fill=green]|8\\
    };
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A31] (A41) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A41] (A4) 
{
    2&1&|[fill=lightgray]|3&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A41] (A42) 
{
    7&5&6&|[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A41] (A51) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A51] (A52) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|3\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A52] (A53) 
{
    2&|[fill=green]|1&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A51] (A54) 
{
    7&5&|[fill=green]|6\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A54] (A55) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A51] (A61) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A61] (A62) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|3\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A62] (A63) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|1&2&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A61] (A64) 
{
    5&|[fill=lightgray]|6&7\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A64] (A65) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, no you cannot nest tikz matrices.

Answer (score 2):

As its name suggests, a `matrix of nodes` is composed of `nodes` and therefore each `node` has a **name** in the form of the `<matrix name>-<row number>-<column number>`.

Here, I have aligned the third matrix under `node 4` (named `A2-1-4`) of the second matrix.

```
   \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A2-1-4] (A31) 
    {
        |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
    };
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum width=8mm, draw},
    },
    ]
    \matrix[mymatrix] (A1) 
    {
        2&8&7&1&3&5&6&|[fill=green]|4\\
    };
 %%%%   
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A1] (A2) 
    {
        2&1&3&|[fill=lightgray]|4&7&5&6&8\\
    };
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A2-1-4] (A31) %<--- alignment of the 4 under the 4
    {
        |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
    };
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A31] (A3) 
    {
        2&1&|[fill=green]|3&\\
    };
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A31] (A32) 
    {
        7&5&6&|[fill=green]|8\\
    };
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A31] (A41) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A41] (A4) 
{
    2&1&|[fill=lightgray]|3&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A41] (A42) 
{
    7&5&6&|[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A41] (A51) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A51] (A52) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|3\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A52] (A53) 
{
    2&|[fill=green]|1&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A51] (A54) 
{
    7&5&|[fill=green]|6\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A54] (A55) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A51] (A61) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A61] (A62) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|3\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A62] (A63) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|1&2&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A61] (A64) 
{
    5&|[fill=lightgray]|6&7\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A64] (A65) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To center the upper two matrices w.r.t. to the lower ones, you can use a `local bounding box` that fits the lower ones and then place the upper ones relative to that local bounding box. This way things will still be centered if you change details in the lower or upper matrices.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum width=8mm, draw},
    },
    ]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=lower]
\matrix[mymatrix] (A31) 
    {
        |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
    };
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A31] (A3) 
    {
        2&1&|[fill=green]|3&\\
    };
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A31] (A32) 
    {
        7&5&6&|[fill=green]|8\\
    };
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A31] (A41) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A41] (A4) 
{
    2&1&|[fill=lightgray]|3&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A41] (A42) 
{
    7&5&6&|[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=5mm of A41] (A51) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A51] (A52) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|3\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A52] (A53) 
{
    2&|[fill=green]|1&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A51] (A54) 
{
    7&5&|[fill=green]|6\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A54] (A55) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
    \matrix[mymatrix, below=1mm of A51] (A61) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|4\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A61] (A62) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|3\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, left=1mm of A62] (A63) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|1&2&\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A61] (A64) 
{
    5&|[fill=lightgray]|6&7\\
};
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, right=1mm of A64] (A65) 
{
    |[fill=lightgray]|8\\
};
\end{scope}
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix, above=5mm of lower] (A2) 
    {
        2&1&3&|[fill=lightgray]|4&7&5&6&8\\
    };
%%%%%
\matrix[mymatrix,above=1mm of A2] (A1) 
    {
        2&8&7&1&3&5&6&|[fill=green]|4\\
    };
%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]